# Calculate start and end time in select query

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
with cte as (
Select 1 as order_num, 'Audi' as car, 7 as total_minutes, null as start_time, null as end_time
union all
Select 2 as order_num, 'BMW' as car, 15 as total_minutes, null as start_time, null as end_time
union all
Select 3 as order_num, 'Mercedes' as car, 5 as total_minutes, null as start_time, null as end_time
)
Select * from cte order by order_num
```

How populate start_time and end_time in query, eg. Start is always 06:00 for order_num = 1  end_time is 06:00 + 7 = 06:07 .... Second row start at 06:07......

Need this as output:

```
1   Audi          7    06:00    06:07
2   BMW           15   06:07    06:22
3   Mercedes      5    06:22    06:27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and `dateadd()`:

```
select cte.*,
       dateadd(minute,
               sum(total_minutes) over (order by order_num) - total_minutes,
               convert(time, '06:00:00')
              ) as start_time,
       dateadd(minute,
               sum(total_minutes) over (order by order_num),
               convert(time, '06:00:00')
              ) as end_time
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7278bcd5274ffd63ca2bdcd13ceb1ba) is a db<>fiddle.

The `sum(total_minutes) over (order by order_num)` does a cumulative sum of the minutes.  The rest is just adding this to the base time.  And, for the start time, the time in the current row is subtracted.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different method, using `ROWS_BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT order_num,
       car,
       total_minutes,
       DATEADD(MINUTE,ISNULL(SUM(total_minutes) OVER (ORDER BY order_num ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0),CONVERT(time,'06:00')),
       DATEADD(MINUTE,ISNULL(SUM(total_minutes) OVER (ORDER BY order_num ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),0),CONVERT(time,'06:00'))
FROM CTE
ORDER BY order_num
```